# Bootstrap control accordion from seperate menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of 4 bootstrap accordions and I'm using a dropdown menu in my navigation to open the accordions.

I can open the accordions but when I open more than one it doesn't close the previously opened accordions, is there a way to close an opened accordion when a another link is clicked?

```
$('li.accordion-nav a').click(function() {
    var aLink = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,'');
    $('#' + aLink).collapse('show', function(){  
        $('.accordion-panel').not('#' + aLink).collapse('hide');
    });
});
```

Comment: I answered your question. If you have any thing to add feel free for comment.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use some thing like this as far as i understand you correctly:

JS:

```
$( "select" ).change(function(e) {
    var val = $("select option:selected").val();
    $('a#' + val).click();
});

$('a[data-parent="#accordion"]').click(function(e) {
    $('select#dropdown').val($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

HTML:

```
 <div>
        <select id='dropdown'>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" id='1'>
              Collapsible Group Item #1
            </a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">
            Anim pariatur cliche 
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      ....
    </div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/j1r634d8/4/)

Comment: Thanks! I tried this originally but must have been doing something wrongended up using: $('a[href="#' + aLink + '"]').click();

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Phoenix help I used this:

```
$('li.accordion-nav a').click(function() {
    var aLink = $(this).attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,'');
    $('a[href="#' + aLink + '"]').click();
    return false;
});
```